# SQL Server - Map column of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, resultset

I have this table:

[image]

I'd like to get to this:

```
EMPID  NAME  MANAGER
  1     a      0
  2     b      a
  3     c      a
  4     d      b
  5     e      c
```

This is what I have tried, but it isn't producing the expected output:

```
SELECT A.Empid, A.Name, REPLACE(A.Name,A.Empid,1)
FROM ChethanQuery A
INNER JOIN ChethanQuery B on A.Empid=B.Empid
```

Comment: Are you asking for a query that will result in that data set? What have you tried? Why are both SQL Server and Postgres tagged when the screenshot clearly shows SSMS? Honestly, this looks like homework to me. I remember almost the exact same question in my SQL class.

Comment: No Sir. i have tried . but i didnt get logic . i need to get result that in one column .ok i will change the tag

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide examples of your attempts thus far.

Comment: select A.Empid,A.Name,Replace(A.Name,A.Empid,1)
from 
ChethanQuery A
inner join
ChethanQuery B
on A.Empid=B.Empid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is close, you just need to select the other name and tweak your join condition:

```
SELECT T.EmpID, T.Name, COALESCE(T2.Name,'0') AS ManagerName
FROM YourTable T
LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON T.Manager = T2.EmpID
```

A `LEFT JOIN` is needed since the 'head' manager will not join to anything, same with the `COALESCE(T2.Name,'0')`

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.

Comment: @sampathacharya Try again now, I forgot to put ticks around the '0' in the coalesce...